# Configurable/virtual product not showing up on website

Tags: configurable-product, virtual-products

I created a class (with a date) as a configurable product for my site. Even when I gave it all the right attributes, making sure it had correct inventory and such, it said it was out of stock. I figured I need to create a virtual product with all the same information and add the date (as a catalog attribute) and a different SKU to resolve it, as it has in the past, but it's not. It still says out of stock, so am I missing something?

Here are the settings I changed from the default settings for both products:

Name, description, short description
SKU (unique)
Status (enabled)
URL Key (same)
Visibility (catalog, search)
Price, no tax
Quantity
Stock Availability (in stock)
Category
Custom option (drop-down menu)

Is there a step I missed or a feature I haven't enabled? Are my configurable and virtual products not merging correctly, if at all? How do I get my product to show as in-stock and have a date be an option for purchase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the configurable and virtual products associated?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your associated products screen (in the parent configurable product)?